# Azure service bus QueueClient per Queue name?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

Do we need to maintain a QueueClient for each queue name in the Service Bus namespace. As it is recommended to cache the QueueClient. I wanted to know if we can have a single QueueClient and use the same for different queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.
The QueueClient instance create a link with the entity "queue" on the service.
Of course more QueueClient instances can share the same TCP connection using the same MessagingFactory to create them.

Paolo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response